# Easiest way to remove dependency on certain ActiveX library in MFC project?

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, activex

I am working on greatly simplifying an old MFC application, and I'd like to use that opportunity to remove a dependency on a certain third-party ActiveX library that has been causing headaches. I first simply tried to remove all references to these controls in the cpp code. It compiles fine, but when installed on a new computer, it crashes if the library .msm file is not included in the setup project.

The problem now is that I don't know where any remaining references to these objects in the project is, and therefore have no easy way of tracking them down and removing them. Simply using the Find-functionality in VS only returns results in cpp files which I've already cleaned up, not any control instances in f.ex. dialog resource files. Is there a way to search for all these objects in the project, or check for them compile-time so that I can use compile errors to see where any library objects remain?

Answer (score 0):

First of all: `CoCreateInstance`, `CoGetClassObject` are the normal ways how COM Objects are created. Should be easy to set break points here or to set a hook to monitor what's going on.

Seams that you have a bad error handling in you software. Otherwise you application should show an error message if an object could not be created.

Try to debug.... use remote debugging, even a crash dump will lead you to the code location.

Easiest approach: In your development machine. Try to look into the output window and see if any of the old ActiveX DLLs gets loaded. Trigger down to the location were any of those objects is created.

You can do the same with remote debugging on the test machine.